# Looking for door ideas for a condo bedroom - tricky wall set up

Tags: walls, doors, door-frame, bedroom, renovation

I will be moving into a condo soon and I know to make sure everything I am doing as far as renovating, is up to code with the HOA. However, I wanted to ask the internet for ideas/pointers since this is not my area of expertise.

I have been looking for the correct term, but my bedroom will be enclosed by walls that do not reach the ceiling. The best lingo I could find were pony walls, but these are much taller than just 3 feet. As of right now, there is no door, but I really would like to find a way to close off the room when I need to. My last resort will be fabric or a divider, but I fear that is no match for my cat.

I had one idea of putting a sliding door but there is no built-in beam across the top, is this still possible if it has been fixed to each side of the doorway? Any other suggestions?

Here's an image of a similar unit, with a similar setup.
[image]

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/DzJiOsn    Here's an image of a similar unit, with the same set up

Comment: Any decent cat can jump onto the worktop, then fridge and then wall and down to the right especially once a bed is there.

Comment: A standard swinging door frame is screwed into the walls on the sides of the frame, with the occasional screw through the top of the frame into the header. A swinging, pre-hung door, in the size necessary for your opening should be just fine without a header. Other door styles, such as sliding or barn doors, may require the installation of some additional framing materials to mount them and hold them secure. However, this vague picture of a wide opening from wall to a kitchen counter doesn't really give us much to work with, and this needs more detail.